# Sum of ten random numbers

Tags: java, arrays, sum

So far, my code looks like this:

```
import java.util.Random;
public class StatsCalculator
{
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    Random r = new Random();
    System.out.println("The ten random values are: ");
    for(int i=0; i<10; i++)
    {
      int randomint = r.nextInt(10);
      System.out.print(" ," + randomint);
    }

    int randomint[];
    int sum=0;
    for(int i : randomint)
    {
      sum += i;
      System.out.println("Sum = " + sum);
    }
  }
}
```

When I run this code, there's an error message come up that say's the following: "variable `randomint` might not have been initialized, `for (int i : randomint)`

Comment: i suggest you rename the array to `randomInts`. its confusing that 2 variables have the same name, especially when they store 2 different things

Answer (score 7):

Try this:

```
int sum=0;
for(int i=0; i<10; i++)
    {
      int randomint = r.nextInt(10);
      System.out.print(" ," + randomint);
      sum = sum + randomint ;
    }

System.out.println("Sum = " + sum);
```

Answer (score 3):

Place all the randoms within an array and then sum them:

```
Random r = new Random();
System.out.println("The ten random values are: ");
int[] values = new int[10];
for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
   int randomint = r.nextInt(10);
   values[i] = randomint;
   System.out.print(" ," + randomint);
}

int sum = 0;
for(int i : values) {
  sum += i;      
}
System.out.println("Sum = " + sum);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your array `randomInt` is defined as an array but elements are never added to it, then you try iterate through it and there's nothing there.

Initialise it

`int[] randomInt = new int[size];`

then create elements in it.  It looks like you should move this to before the first array and add all the random `int` you create.

Answer (score 0):

The error is telling you everything: "variable randomint might not have been initialized, for (int i : randomint)"

In your head, you should hear this dialog:

- Hmm, why is it telling me randomint might not have been initialised? Have I initialised it?
- I better check this randomint...oh, here it is:

  ```
  int randomint[];
  ```
- How do I initialise it...the docs...the docs...[THE DOCS!](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html) 
  Here it is:

> One way to create an array is with the new operator. The next statement in the ArrayDemo program allocates an array with enough memory for 10 integer elements and assigns the array to the anArray variable.

```
// create an array of integers
int[] anArray = new int[10];
```

> If this statement is missing, then the compiler prints an error like the following, and compilation fails:
>
> **ArrayDemo.java:4: Variable anArray may not have been initialised.**

- Fine, let's add this:

  int randomint[] = new int[10];
- compile...run...
- errr, why is the sum 0 if I can see random numbers?

  (reads the docs again)
- Right, need to store those random ints in my array, phew, one more change:

  ```
  Random r = new Random();
  System.out.println("The ten random values are: ");

  int randomint[] = new int[10];

  for(int i=0; i<10; i++)
  {
      randomint[i] = r.nextInt(10);
      System.out.print(" ," + randomint[i]);
  }

  int sum=0;
  for(int i : randomint)
  {
      sum += i;
      System.out.println("Sum = " + sum);
  }
  ```
- Uff, next time someone asks similar question on SO, I might be able help them. First thing I'll say is to read the docs :)